# CREATE TABLE with Dynamic Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I need to insert some data into a temp table.

I have some ***conditional based columns like `Salary`, `Code`***.

How can I create a table for conditional based columns? **I don't want to use** 
**`SELECT INTO #tempTable`**

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@sqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100))


SET @sqlSelect ='INSERT INTO #myTempTable
SELECT EMP.Id, EMP.DeptId, EMP.DeptName'

SET @sqlFrom =' FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE AS EMP'

IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +', EMP.Salary, EMP.Code'            
END

SET @sql =  @sqlSelect +@sqlFrom 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Any help/suggestion on how better i can make this?

---

**Update:**

Initially I used `SELECT INTO #TempTable` without specifying no of columns, As SQL Azure not supporting that, I decided to go with `INSERT INTO`. But not sure how can I add dynamic columns in a defined structure already. Its fully dynamic SQL :(

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, Updated my question. See update part for more information

Comment: You cannot add columns to tables dynamically. You need to have all columns defined upfront.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, So i need to CREATE a Table including Salary, Code columns, even if they are not in select? If that is the case which order it will insert if i select only 3 columns? Sorry i am not a good in sql.

Comment: Correct, you need to create all columns that you may need. If a column is optional, make it nullable by adding `NULL` after its data type, like this: `Salary money NULL`. If you insert a row that does not include `Salary`, `NULL` would be inserted.

Comment: Any columns that may get no data will need to be NULLABLE. Other than that the insert should work fine

Comment: Fine. Still i need to handle lot to do with NULL in all the conditional based columns for the INSERT Statement

Comment: @BadDeveloper When inserting the data, do you know what kind of data you are inserting? If so, then your insert statement shouldn't be a problem, as you can just insert into the column representing that item of data.

Comment: @rhughes, they are DateTime, INT, NVARCHAR, IMAGE type also

Comment: @BadDeveloper I mean, is your data: `Name`, `Phone Number`, `Photo` etc...?

Comment: @rhughes, Yes. But anyway i gave you types too :)

Comment: Define your `CREATE #myTempTable` in dynamic sql also. Add dynamic column inside it. It will have dynamic column. Otherwise, declare "all" the column in the temptable as nullable, then fill only what you need

Comment: @Fendy, you mean ALTER Table in Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @BadDeveloper No, `CREATE TABLE #myTempTable` in dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

How many dynamic columns do you need?

What about having a column called `Dynamic` of type `nvarchar(MAX)` or something of the like, and then you can just put your data in there and format as appropriate.

Another option is to create a table with `NULL` columns.

To do this in SQL, you can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tblPerson
(
    PersonId INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(256),
    LastName NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonId)
)
```

Notice the `NULL` column above also.

See here for further explanation on creating tables with `Primary Keys` and `NULL` columns in SQL:

[Create tables in SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)

Comment: They are around 10+ columns.

Comment: As you mentioned you need them dynamically, do you need them all at the same time?

Comment: Assume i have default columns 5 and i will take 2 or more columns that gets added in one or more If statement that satisfy some condition

Comment: OK. It seems your best bet is to use the NULL method mentioned above. Databases are hard coded by design, they are not dynamic. If you truly need your database to be that dynamic, you may look into `In RAM` databases

Comment: Can  you help me on syntax for handling NULL? Sorry am bad in SQL. Just learning :(

Comment: Fine. This is simple how about doing INSERT statement as i mentioned in dynamic query?

Comment: What are you inserting into? you can't just magically create columns when you insert into an existing table. Is this a new project? You might want to look into RavenDB or other document based db which allows you to just add attributes as needed since there is no schema.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to, your best bet is to likely create all of the columns that you will need and make them NULLable if optional.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100), Salary INT NULL, EmpCode VARCHAR(45) NULL);
```

And

```
IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +', EMP.Salary, EMP.Code'            
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +', NULL, NULL'            
END
```

Answer (score 0):

See example below:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(400)
declare @ColFlag int
set @ColFlag = 1
if(@ColFlag = 0)

set  @sql= 'CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100)); 
    INSERT INTO #myTempTable SELECT 1,2,''DeptName1''; 
    SELECT * FROM #myTempTable'
else
set  @sql= 'CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100), MyNewColHere VARCHAR(25)); 
    INSERT INTO #myTempTable SELECT 1,2,''DeptName1'', ''MyNewColHereValue''; 
    SELECT * FROM #myTempTable'

 exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code may work for you.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@sqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100))    
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100),Salary numeric(18,2), Code INT)    
END

SET @sqlSelect ='INSERT INTO #myTempTable
SELECT EMP.Id, EMP.DeptId, EMP.DeptName'

SET @sqlFrom =' FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE AS EMP'

IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +', EMP.Salary, EMP.Code'            
END

SET @sql =  @sqlSelect +@sqlFrom 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You could just alter the temp table when the condition is met (I'm assuming you know the columns required at this point?)

```
IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE #myTempTable ADD Salary VARCHAR(20), Code VARCHAR(20)
    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +', EMP.Salary, EMP.Code'            
END
```

You may want to test if the column exists first, if you have more than one condition that could be activated - which you can do like so:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('#myTemptable','Salary') IS NULL
BEGIN
     -- do something if salary doesn't exist
     ALTER TABLE #myTempTable ADD Salary NUMERIC(6,2)
END
```

As others have noted, you could create the columns upfront as nullable - or create the table after the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

command to change the name of a previously defined place holder column.
For example, create the `#tempTable` with extra fields such as `"VCHAR100_1"`, `"BOOL_1"`, `"Int_1"`, etc.  If you need to use the field, rename it to the desired name so your code later on can refer to the column by a non-cryptic name.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really are looking for is impossible for SQL. As I undrestand you want to add column for, for example tuples that met the conditions. So I think you need some other database engines like NoSQL(I'm not very familiar with NoSQL but as much as I know it can horizontally scale)
If you don't want to switch from sql I think you should reconsider your design.
 If you insist on your design you can do things like for example add a column, name "column name" and another column "column data" and fill it when its needed. But as you can see it has its own constraints like the data of "column data" should be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

use the code and tell me is it working or not ??

```
-----------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@sqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tblInfo (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100))    
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tblInfo (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100),Salary numeric(18,2), Code INT)    
END

SET @sqlSelect ='INSERT INTO #tblInfo 
SELECT EMP.Id, EMP.DeptId, EMP.DeptName'

SET @sqlFrom =' FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE AS EMP'

IF (someCondition)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +', EMP.Salary, EMP.Code'            
END

SET @sql =  @sqlSelect +@sqlFrom 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

------------------------------------
```

I hope it will work

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

If this table is BIG I think your and in your logic you make JOINS with this table you need to create indexes in TARGET TABLE

You can go around with Physical table not TEMP

```
DECLARE @guid NVARCHAR(64), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@sqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) ='', @sqlSchema NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

SET @guid = NEWID()  

declare @tableName NVARCHAR(64)= 'myTempTable'+ @guid

select @tableName

--use some transaction

set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName  
set @sqlSchema = '(Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100)'  -- DO INDEXES IF YOU ARE JOIN 

SET @sqlSelect ='INSERT INTO ' + @tableName +
'SELECT EMP.Id, EMP.DeptId, EMP.DeptName'


IF (1=1) -- your condition
BEGIN
  SET @sqlSchema = @sqlSchema +', EMP.Salary, EMP.Code'            
END

SET @sqlSchema =   @sqlSchema + ')' -- close last )

set @sql =  @sql +@sqlSchema --create the TargetTable


--DO YOUR logic

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

set @sql = N'DROP TABLE ' + @tableName

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Begin Tran


IF (someCondition)

    Begin 
      CREATE TABLE #myTempTable (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100), Salary money , Code Int)

        Insert Into #myTempTable(Id, DeptId, DeptName, Salary, Code)
        Select Emp.Id, Emp.DeptID, Emp.DeptName, EMP.Salary, EMP.Code 
        From dbo.Employee As Emp

        Select Id, DeptID, DeptName, Salary, Code From dbo.Employee
              Drop Table #myTempTable     
    End

    Else

    Begin

      CREATE TABLE #myTempTable2 (Id INT, DeptId INT, DeptName VARCHAR(100))

        Insert Into #myTempTable(Id, DeptId, DeptName)
        Select Emp.Id, Emp.DeptID, Emp.DeptName 
        From dbo.Employee As Emp

        Select Id, DeptID, DeptName From dbo.Employee

                    Drop Table #myTempTable2 
    End



Commit Tran
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with completely dynamic columns:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@sqlTableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
,@sqlColumnsDefinitions NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
,@sqlColumnsList NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

SET @sqlTableName = 'myTempTable'
SET @sqlFrom = 'FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE AS EMP'

--conditions to define columns
IF (1=1)
    set @sqlColumnsDefinitions='Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int'
else
    set @sqlColumnsDefinitions='Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 int, Col4 int, Col5 int'

--new table with dynamic fields creation
SET @sql = 'if (object_id('''+@sqlTableName+''') is not null) DROP TABLE '+@sqlTableName+'
CREATE TABLE '+@sqlTableName+' ('+@sqlColumnsDefinitions+')'+char(10)
print (@sql)
exec (@sql)

--get columns list
select @sqlColumnsList=STUFF((SELECT ',' + column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name like @sqlTableName+'%' FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

--main insert
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO '+@sqlTableName+char(10)+'SELECT '+@sqlColumnsList+char(10)+@sqlFrom
print (@sql)
exec  (@sql)
```

This won't work if you substite myTempTable with #myTempTable because of SQL engine. To fix it and get correct column names list you may use some tricks that are out of scope. But still it works with non-temp tables.